# Automapper flatten entity to dto

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am having a bit of trouble with automapper at the moment.

I have a Lead entity with the following properties

```
Id as long

FirstName as string

LastName as string

Title as string

LeadOpportunities as ICollection(Of ILeadOpportunity)
```

LeadOpportunity contains the following properties

```
SourceDate as datetime

LeadOpportunityType as LeadOpportunityType
```

LeadOpportunityType contains the following property

```
Description as string
```

I have a LeadSearchDTO which has the following properties

```
LeadId as long

LastActionDate as datetime

Title as string

FirstName as string

LastName as string

Type as string
```

I have the following in my bootstrapper class.

```
Mapper.CreateMap(Of List(Of ILead), List(Of ILeadSearchDTO))()

Mapper.CreateMap(Of ILead, ILeadSearchDTO)().ForMember(Function(en) en.LeadId, Sub(map) map.MapFrom(Function(dto) dto.Id)) _
                                                    .ForMember(Function(en) en.LastActionDate, Sub(map) map.MapFrom(Function(dto) dto.LeadOpportunities.FirstOrDefault().SourceDate)) _
                                                    .ForMember(Function(en) en.Type, Sub(map) map.MapFrom(Function(dto) dto.LeadOpportunities.FirstOrDefault().LeadOpportunityType.Description))
```

I am then using the following code to map the two objects.

```
response.LeadDTOs = Me._mapper.Map(Of List(Of ILead), List(Of ILeadSearchDTO))(leads)
```

When I put my break point over response.LeadDTOs it does not map from the leads collection.

Does anyone have an idea of what I might be missing? I have only just started using automapper for just over a week and I have just been using simple conversions so far.

EDIT:

If I leave out Mapper.CreateMap(Of List(Of ILead), List(Of ILeadSearchDTO))() it will give me the following error message.

```
Mapping types:
ILead -> ILeadSearchDTO
_8T.DataHub.Model.Interfaces.Entities.Lead.ILead ->  _8T.DataHub.Service.Interfaces.DTOs.Lead.ILeadSearchDTO

Destination path:
List`1[0]

Source value:
_8T.DataHub.Model.Implementation.Entities.Lead.Lead
```

I already have Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid() included as well.

Comment: You must map to a concrete class, AutoMapper can't materialize an interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it in the end.

I had to use the following code.

```
ConstructUsing(Function(x As ResolutionContext) New LeadSearchDTO())
```

Comment: No, you should have done `Mapper.CreateMap(Of ILead, LeadSearchDTO)` (no interface as target type).

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to call

```
Mapper.CreateMap(Of List(Of ILead), List(Of ILeadSearchDTO))()
```

Automapper will handle lists automatically. But anyway, try to call

```
Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

after last `CreateMap`.